# How to mount a RAID array on a Linux server if it does not appear to be listed?

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive, mount, hardware-raid

I am helping to administer two CentOS 5 servers, on the "user" side of things. A RAID 1 array and a separate single hard drive were recently added by IT support. According to the IT support, both of these are ready to be mounted on either of the servers.

However, I don't see the RAID array or the single hard drive, e.g. using the `fdisk -l` or `cat /proc/partitions` commands.

I assume there must be a way for the user to find and mount these drives in a somewhat standard way. What would be the steps for doing this?

(I would prefer not to ask the IT support because they technically have no responsibility to assist with these particular servers, and they are quite unresponsive about them. We also do not have physical access to the server room.)

Comment: If the system indeed supports hot adding storage - you may need to use the raid controller configuration tool to configure how the new disk(s) will be presented to your OS (the how/commands depend on which controller) - then re-scan the SCSI bus to instruct the OS to start looking newly added disks (forgot the specific command options for ancient CentOS 5 but please Google that ) - you may simply need  to reboot (and possibly enter the RAID controllers bios during startup)

Comment: Two questions to consider. What is the vendor of both the server and the storage? Not all servers are capable of hot adding of storage.
As @HermanB mentions CentOS 5 is a bit old, so a reboot might help to detect the new disks. Regards, Jan Gerrit Kootstra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new RAID array turned out to be on a new RAID controller. The old one is Adaptec 5805, and the new one is Adaptec 8805.

Even the v.3.03 configuration utility `arcconf` from Adaptec, which was released quite a bit later than Adaptec 8805, couldn not detect the new RAID controller.

The issue appears to be that the currently installed AACRAID driver from Adapter is version 1.1.5, but the first driver version that supports the new Adaptec 8805 on RHEL 5 (and thus CentOS 5) is v1.2.1-40300.